# How to create applications like Balsamiq Mockups

Tags: wireframe, balsamiq

Which are the languages used for creating WireFraming/Mockups applications like Balsamiq Mockups? Mainly web application.

Do they use HTML5 Canvas API? or Flash/Flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old question, but I'll give it a stab:

Balsamiq has two versions: 'Desktop' and 'myBalsamiq', both of which run on the Adobe Flash platform. The Desktop version runs on Adobe Air Player, and myBalsamiq (web version) runs on the Adobe Flash Player in your web browser. Both of these versions are created using Flex.

A screengrab of the Help|About from my Desktop version shows that it runs on Adobe Air Player.

[image: Screengrab of Desktop Help|About]

Answer (score 0):

New update:
I think nowadays [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) is a good solution

> If you can build a website, you can build a desktop app. Electron is a
> framework for creating native applications with web technologies like
> JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. It takes care of the hard parts so you can
> focus on the core of your application.

there are many desktop apps built with this framework. including [Figma](https://www.figma.com/).

[This link](https://www.electronjs.org/apps) is a list of all desktop apps built with it.